# ggplot creates artefacts in plot with geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two vectors x,y and want to create a line plot for y over x.

```
y =  c(-0.0400785, -0.0304795, -0.0208800, -0.0112805, -0.0016810,  0.0079185,  0.0175180,  0.0271175,
       0.0367170,  0.0463160,  0.0559155,  0.0655150,  0.0751145,  0.0847140,  0.0943135,  0.1039130,
       0.1135125,  0.1231120,  0.1327110,  0.1423105,  0.1519100)

x = c(-5.867304, -5.879089, -5.987021, -6.309500, -6.770748, -7.189354, -7.455675, -7.545589, -7.463138,
      -7.371971, -7.407384, -7.461245, -7.398057, -7.192540, -7.010408, -6.961792, -6.994748, -6.971052,
      -6.779542, -6.536575, -6.301766)
```

If I use the base plot function everything is fine.

```
plot(x,y, type = "l")
```

If I create a line plot using ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame("y" = y, "x" = x)
ggplot(data = df) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

It introduces strange artefacts, as if wrong x are ordered to wrong y. Does anyone have the same experience and even better a solution for that problem?

Comment: Please have a look at `?geom_line`: "Connect observations, **ordered by x value**.". Compare with `?geom_path`: "Connect observations in **original order**".

Comment: I formed a mental figure of `geom_line` as a function in math: takes no multiple values for single x. `geom_path` is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `geom_path`:

```
ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]